# Rails multi-level relation destroyed when updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, foreign-keys, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a four-level deep model structure: Domain > Subject > Device > Property

```
class Domain < ApplicationRecord 
    has_many :subjects
  end

  class Subject < ApplicationRecord 
    has_many :devices 
    belongs_to: :domain
  end

  class Device < ApplicationRecord 
    has_many :properties
    belongs_to: :subject
  end

  class Property < ApplicationRecord 
    belongs_to :device
  end
```

controller code

```
def update
  result = @subject.update(parameters)
  if result
    render json: @subject
  else
    render_errors(@subject.errors)
  end
end
```

`@subject` is retrieved as a before action, by querying the model tree from domain onwards, using `domain_id` and `id` parameters for domain and subject respectively. `parameters` is simply a hash of parameters, e.g. `{name: :new_name}`

When updating a Subject, the relation to domain is lost, i.e. `domain_id` is set to NUL by rails. The entire model tree below subject will also be disconnected from the parent domain as a result.

When removing `has_many: :devices` from the Subject model, everything works as expected. I just want to update a subject and preserve the relation to the parent domain. How would I achieve this with the model described above?

**EDIT 1 - Added log of both situations.**

Log with full relational model (that results in the bug)

```
    Domain Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "domains".* FROM "domains" WHERE "domains"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["name", "Manatree"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "domains".* FROM "domains" WHERE "domains"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["name", "Manatree"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Subject Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "subjects".* FROM "subjects" WHERE "subjects"."domain_id" = ? AND "subjects"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["domain_id", 3], ["name", "s1"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Subject Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "subjects".* FROM "subjects" WHERE "subjects"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  Domain Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "domains".* FROM "domains" WHERE "domains"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (7.1ms)  UPDATE "subjects" SET "domain_id" = NULL WHERE "subjects"."domain_id" = ? AND "subjects"."id" = 5  [["domain_id", 3]]
  Subject Exists (0.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "subjects" WHERE "subjects"."domain_id" = ? AND "subjects"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["domain_id", 3], ["name", "s2"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (1.0ms)  UPDATE "subjects" SET "name" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "subjects"."id" = ?  [["name", "s2"], ["updated_at", "2017-07-31 08:46:38.171240"], ["id", 5]]
   (7.5ms)  commit transaction
  Subject Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "subjects".* FROM "subjects"
Completed 200 OK in 30ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 16.6ms)
```

Log when removing `belongs_to: :devices` from Subject model

```
Domain Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "domains".* FROM "domains" WHERE "domains"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["name", "Manatree"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "domains".* FROM "domains" WHERE "domains"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["name", "Manatree"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Subject Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "subjects".* FROM "subjects" WHERE "subjects"."domain_id" = ? AND "subjects"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["domain_id", 3], ["name", "s3"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Subject Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "subjects".* FROM "subjects" WHERE "subjects"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  Domain Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "domains".* FROM "domains" WHERE "domains"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (6.5ms)  UPDATE "subjects" SET "name" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "subjects"."id" = ?  [["name", "s4"], ["updated_at", "2017-07-31 08:48:57.962218"], ["id", 6]]
   (7.0ms)  commit transaction
  Subject Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "subjects".* FROM "subjects"
Completed 200 OK in 25ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 15.1ms)
```

**Edit 2 - There might be something wrong with the seed data...**

```
domainA = Domain.create(name: :company)
s1 = domainA.subjects.create(name: :subject)
# domainA.save
d1 = s1.devices.create(name: :device)
# s1.save
p1 = d1.properties.create(name: :prop1, property_type: :double, value: 10.0)
p2 = d1.properties.create(name: :prop2, property_type: :string, value: :on)
p3 = d1.properties.create(name: :prop3, property_type: :string, value: :Lamp)
# d1.save
domainA.save
```

Comment: does this happen when you save an instance of subject in the rails console ?

Comment: Why is the `domain_id` being set to `nil`? What parameters are you sending, and what is the `SubjectsController` doing (assuming the error you're talking about is coming from the controller action)? I don't see how removing `has_many :devices` should affect this behaviour at all. Can you try to provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Is the `parameters` is a method? If so, show us that code. Also the log that is generated should help too.

Comment: @Pavan I exlcuded parameters from being the culprit. I actually hardcoded a valid params hash in the update method --> `@subject.update({name: :non_existing_new_name})`. Still, the bug remains...

Comment: You should be using strong params. I'm still want to see your log. Can you show us?

Comment: Are you updating subject through the form? What params are passed to the update action?

Comment: @Pavan I am updating a subject through a http request. My application is a pure REST service. Parameters are a change of `name`.

Comment: @Snake Through console I get expected behavior (nothing is wrong). Maybe there is something wrong with my `seeds` file?! If I continue from the data put into the database from the rails console, everything also works doing the rest api requests from Postman when the server is running...

Answer (score 1):

> When removing has_many: :devices from the Subject model, everything
>   works as expected.

Going on with your models, Your `Device` model is flawed. You have `belongs_to :device` inside `Device`. Perhaps you should have `belongs_to :subject` as per the associations. This could have lead to your current problem. Try changing the `Device` model like so

```
class Device < ApplicationRecord 
  has_many :properties
  belongs_to: :subject
end
```

Comment: the flaw in the `Device` model has been a typo... The code was actually as you described, i.e. your suggestion does not solve the problem sadly
Updated the quesiton description.

Comment: @KevinvandenBekerom OK. Show us how you are updating the subject. The necessary code and the log should help